# git reset a pushed file to a previous commit

Tags: git, version-control, rebase, git-checkout

I have pushed some changes to my `feature` branch.

`file_a` has been changed on the `master` branch.

Now, I would like to keep my changes, but for `file_a` I want it to be the same as the one in `master`

I don't want to do heavy merges, so I decided to reset my file to a previous commit (the one before my own push)

```
git checkout aaaaaaa -- file_a
```

Now, the file's **content** resets to what I had before making changes, but it's not reset to that commit. Now I have uncommitted changes.

**Problem**: I cannot do a `git pull origin master --rebase`. I cannot stash the change, because my edit will appear. I don't want to commit it, because it becomes a new commit and then I cannot rebase without a merge (there will be conflicts with my previous edit)

**What I'm looking for**: is for `file_a` (not just its content) to be reset to that exact commit before my edit, such that I can rebase without merging. Would that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the neatest solution that came to my mind was to

`git reset --soft aaaaaaa`

Then I have all of my edits staged. I then unstage and discard changes on `file_a` and do my normal rebase workflow

```
git stash
git pull origin master --rebase
git stash pop
add <directory>
git commit
git push --force-with-lease
```

This way all the changes are preserved, `file_a` gets the updated version, and no merges are required. `feature` changes will be rebased on top of the latest `master`